# javascript: how to select and parse a file

Tags: javascript

Javascript novice, looking to write a program that takes an input file, `filenames.txt`, tests each line to see if it contains a file path that is > 256 characters, and then outputs the results both as on-screen text and as a serializable format, i.e. .csv

here's the code that I have so far, I'm asking how to access the file selected and parse it for paths longer than 256 characters

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>256 character finder</title>
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.0.2/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>


<body>

    Pick a file:
    <br>
    <input id="lefile" type="file" style="display:none">

    <div class="input-append">
       <input id="fileSelect" class="input-large" type="text">
       <a class="btn" onclick="$('input[id=lefile]').click();">Browse</a>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" value="whatever" class="field left" readonly>
    </div>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[id=lefile]').change(function() {
           $('#fileSelect').val($(this).val());
        });

    }

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: you're going to need to use a file uploader.

Comment: Look at the [file api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications), right now you are looking at the name of the file.

Comment: You should use a server sided script (e.g. php) to read and parse your text file and to save the results as a csv file.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/Fcg2X/

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[type=file]').change(function() {
        if (!("files" in this)) {
            alert("File reading not supported in this browser");
        }
        var file = this.files && this.files[0];
        if (!file) {
            return;
        }
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function(e) {
            var text = e.target.result;
            //do something with text
            document.body.innerHTML = text;
        };
        fileReader.readAsText(this.files[0]);
    });
});
```

Btw non-supporting browsers include IE9 so be aware. Has been working for years in Firefox and Chrome though.